# Refining open covering of a metrizable space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the following collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$: 
$\mathcal{A} = \{(n, n +2)|n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.
Which of the following collections refine $\mathcal{A}$?

$\mathcal{B} = \{\left(x, x + 1 \right): x \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

$\mathcal{C} = \{\left(n, n + 1 + \frac{1}{2} \right): n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

$\mathcal{D} = \{\left(x, x + 1 + \frac{1}{2} \right): x \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

Idea: The book (Munkres) has a construction of an open covering refining a given covering which satisfies even an extra condition of being countably locally finite.  The construction picks an element $U \in \mathcal{A}$, and then defines $S_{n}(U) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: B(x, \frac{1}{n}) \}$.

$E_{n}(U) = \bigcup_{x \in S_{n}(U)\backslash \cup_{V \subset U}V}B(x, \frac{1}{3n})$.
Then $\mathcal{E} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\{E_{n}(U): U\in \mathcal{A} \}$ is the desired refinement of $\mathcal{A}$ since each $V \in \mathcal{A}$ is $E_{n}$ - invariant. 
I thought I could just emulate this construction and get something concrete dropping out in terms of the choices given, but I did not see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

- Show that for any $x\in\Bbb R$, $(x,x+1)\subseteq(\lfloor x\rfloor,\lfloor x\rfloor+2)$.
- For each $C\in\mathscr{C}$ it’s very easy to find an $A\in\mathscr{A}$ such that $C\subseteq A$; how?
- For $\mathscr{D}$ consider $x=\frac34$.